# append in multiple div condition wise jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, append, response, prepend

I have an issue while appending the PHP response data in div condition-wise.
I am trying to append the data if `type=='I'` then it will append in other div OR if `type=='A'` then it will append in other div.

The code which I am made is not working, even I try multiples time not achieve the goal.
I also read the other threads but it was not helpful for me in my case.
Please help me ...

How I goal the achieve and make code correct.

```js
var mytable = $("table#table");
var mytableWithHeader = mytable.append('<thead><tr><th style="width: 20%; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">Name/House</th><th style="width: 10%; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">Age/Rent</th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody>');
$.each(response.data, function(i, item) {
  mytableWithHeader.find('tbody').append(`
    <tr>
      <td>${item.name}</td> 
      <td>${item.age}</td>
    </tr>
  `);
});

//I am trying to do is below -
$.each(response.data, function(i, item) {
  if ({item.type } == 'I') {
    mytableWithHeader.find('tbody').append(`
    <tr>
      $("div.tab1").prepend("
        <td>${item.name}</td> 
        <td>${item.age}</td>
      ");
      </tr>
    `);
  }

  if ({ item.type } == 'A') {
    mytableWithHeader.find('tbody').append(`
    <tr>
      $("div.tab2").prepend("
        <td>${item.house}</td> 
        <td>${item.rent}</td>
      ");
      </tr>
    `);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab1">    
 <table id="table"></table>
</div>

<div class="tab2">    
 <table id="table"></table>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you have a dollar sign and braces in your `if` statement? An error is thrown at `if ($ {item.type } == 'I') {`

Comment: I've enabled the console in your snippet. Run it to see the error.

Comment: Are you really trying to put literal jQuery code into the table?

Comment: What @isherwood is trying to point out is that `if ($ {item.type } == 'I')` should be `if (item.type == 'I')`. You only put `${}` around variables in template literals.

Comment: Typo: `</r>` should be `</tr>`

Comment: @Barmar it's a typo error while creating the threads but originally it's right in my real code.

Comment: @isherwood When I remove `$` still I am getting the error in console and code not working. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'`

Comment: I will feel so thankful to you, please help to fix this problem I am bit fresh in jQuery

Comment: not its working but not append the data `type == I OR A` wise

Answer (score 0):

Simplified version with fixes to the repeating ID in the tables and only using the conditionals to assign variables then only processing those variables once after the conditionals

```js
$("table.tab_table").append('<thead><tr><th style="width: 20%; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">Name/House</th><th style="width: 10%; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">Age/Rent</th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody>');

$.each(response.data, function(i, item){ 
    const {type, house, rent, name, age} = item;
    let $cont, rowItems ;

    if(type === 'A'){
       $cont = $('.tab2');
       rowItems = [house, rent];              
    }else{
       $cont = $('.tab1');
       rowItems = [name, age];         
    }

    const $cells = rowItems.map(txt => $('<td>').text(txt)), 
          $row = $('<tr>').append($cells);

    $cont.find('table').append($row);
});
```

```css
td{text-align:center}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab1">    
 <table class="tab_table"></table>
</div>

<div class="tab2">    
 <table class="tab_table"></table>
</div>

<script>
const response = {
   data:[
     {type:'I', name:'Mr Foo', age:37},
     {type:'I', name:'Mrs Bar', age:93},
     {type:'A', house:'big', rent:200},
     {type:'A', house:'small', rent:100}     
   ]
}
</script>
```